# Can I select 2 tables data in one table with a sum values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables linked with a foreign key,  Customer and Orders table

Table Customers

| Cust_ID | Cust_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Tom |

Orders

| order_id | Cust_ID | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Java Book |
| 2 | 1 | Payton Book |
| 3 | 2 | MySQL Book |

So how many Book 'John' Ordered?

I wanna to show like this, please anyone help me: show me the query.

| name | order |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Tomi | 1 |

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT()

Comment: yes Akina, but I want  the query write the query, please

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select name, count(*) as order from Customers join Orders on Customers.Cust_ID = Orders.Cust_ID group by Customers.CustID;
```

Comment: Thank you Chris Lear. you solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
SELECT   Cust_name, count(o.order_id) as Orders
FROM     Customers c 
JOIN     Orders o 
  ON       
           c.Cust_ID = o.Cust_ID 

GROUP BY   c.CustID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with join and group by clause or using subquery. Since you want to use `order` as column alias and it's a reserve word you need to wrap it with double quotes("order").

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Customers(Cust_ID int, Cust_name varchar(50));
 insert into customers values(1,    'John');
 insert into customers values(2,    'Tom');
 
 
 create table Orders(order_id int,  Cust_ID  int, Orders varchar(50));
 insert into Orders values(1,   1,  'Java Book');
 insert into Orders values(2,   1,  'Payton Book');
 insert into Orders values(3,   2,  'MySQL Book');
```

Query#1 (using join and group by clause)

```
 SELECT   Cust_name name, count(o.order_id) as "order"
 FROM     Customers c 
 JOIN     Orders o 
   ON       
            c.Cust_ID = o.Cust_ID 
 GROUP BY   c.Cust_name;
```

Output:

| name | order |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Tom | 1 |

Query:(using subquery)

```
 SELECT   Cust_name name, (select count(order_id) from Orders o where o.Cust_ID=c.Cust_ID) as "order"
 FROM     Customers c
```

Output:

| name | order |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Tom | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=696a3e4f7ea767d1c3d087a8131d18d3)*

Comment: Thank you Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur. you solve my problem.

Comment: You are most welcome @merobi. Best wishes.